# Why do I get memory leaks while properly deallocating memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

That's all the code with allocation and deallocation

Constructor

```
 Event::Event(){
    setEmpty();
}
```

Destructor

```
    Event::~Event(){
    delete [] event_description;
}
```

Copy constructor

```
Event::Event(const Event& Event){
      if (Event.event_description == nullptr) {
          event_description = nullptr;

      } else {
           event_description = new char[strlen(Event.event_description)+1];
          strcpy(event_description, Event.event_description);

      }
    time_in_sec = Event.time_in_sec;
}
```

Copy assignment operator

```
Event& Event::operator=(const Event& Event){
    delete [] event_description;
    if (Event.event_description == nullptr) {
        event_description = nullptr;

    } else {
         event_description = new char[strlen(Event.event_description)+1];
        strcpy(event_description, Event.event_description);
    }


 time_in_sec = Event.time_in_sec;

    return *this;
}
```

Function that sets description in further development.
**The main task is to dynamically allocate memory for the event description. I get memory leaks while checking through valgrind**

```
void Event::setDescription(const char* new_desc){
    if (new_desc == nullptr || new_desc[0] == '\0') {

        event_description = nullptr;
        time_in_sec = 0;
    } else {
        event_description = new char[strlen(new_desc)+1];
        strcpy(event_description, new_desc);
        time_in_sec = g_sysClock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `std::string` for your strings? Then you could follow the rule of zero and get rid of the copy-constructor, destructor and copy-assignment operator.

Comment: Why do STL containers like `std::vector` or `std::queue` not suffice you?

Comment: `event_description = nullptr;` This loses track of any previously allocated buffer without freeing it. If for example you call `setDescription` twice in a row, the first allocation is leaked.

Comment: As for the possible leaks, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that replicates the behavior. And also please include a copy-paste of the Valgrind output (which, if you build with debug information, will contain information about *where* the leaks happened).

Comment: Asan aside, *const Event& Event* has the potential to confuse, consider making your variable name lower case so you can easily distinguish it from the class.

Comment: The reasons why you should include a minimum reproducible example is that a) it’s much easier to debug if we can mess with the code ourselves, and b) it’s easy to forget an important bit otherwise, such as `setEmpty` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This function

```
void Event::setDescription(const char* new_desc){
    if (new_desc == nullptr || new_desc[0] == '\0') {

        event_description = nullptr;
        time_in_sec = 0;
    } else {
        event_description = new char[strlen(new_desc)+1];
        strcpy(event_description, new_desc);
        time_in_sec = g_sysClock;
    }
}
```

produces memory leaks. It does not delete the previous allocated memory the address to which is stored in the data member event_description.

It should be defined at least like

```
void Event::setDescription(const char* new_desc){
    delete [] event_description;   

    if (new_desc == nullptr || new_desc[0] == '\0') {
        event_description = nullptr;
        time_in_sec = 0;
    } else {
        event_description = new char[strlen(new_desc)+1];
        strcpy(event_description, new_desc);
        time_in_sec = g_sysClock;
    }
}
```

A more safer approach can look like

```
void Event::setDescription(const char* new_desc){
    if (new_desc == nullptr || new_desc[0] == '\0') {
        delete [] event_description;   
        event_description = nullptr;
        time_in_sec = 0;
    } else {
        char *tmp = new char[strlen(new_desc)+1];
        delete [] event_description;
        event_description = tmp;
        strcpy(event_description, new_desc);
        time_in_sec = g_sysClock;
    }
}
```